# How can I preserve leading zeros when exporting sql query output as a csv file?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

The SQL column containing leading zeros is a varchar. When I export as an excel file, the leading zeros are preserved. However, when I export as csv, the leading zeros are gone.

When I upload the excel data output file into python using pandas pd.ExcelFile, the leading zeros are also gone in the pandas dataframe. Datatype in the pandas dataframe for this column in int64.

Comment: Side note: Excel is not CSV, and make sure to not confuse the two. Excel is IMO terrible with CSVs, prefer a text editor like Notepad(++).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.